# passing docker swarm secret to sibling container

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, docker-swarm, docker-in-docker, docker-secrets

I have a docker swarm which I start with this compose file:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /run/secrets:/run/secrets
    secrets:
      - my-secret
secrets:
  my-secret:
    file: my_secret.txt
```

Now, within the container running `my_service`, I start a new sibling container (note I've mounted the docker socket), which I want to have access to `my-secret`, although it's not part of the swarm.
What's the best way to do this?

Simply mounting the secrets as a volume (`docker run -v /run/secrets:/run/secrets sibling_image`) doesn't work, the sibling container can see `my-secret`, but it's empty.

Passing an environment variable works, but it's a little too cumbersome if I have many secrets: `docker run -it --env MY_SECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/my-secret) sibling_image`

Comment: Why don't you run the sibling container as another service? That way you can pass the secret via Swarm.

Comment: @geselix the swarm is my Jenkins, and the sibling container is the build agent which is started by Jenkins Pipeline on every build. I provide it with a Dockerfile and Jenkins runs `docker build` and `docker run` (with some parameters I can override).